# Remove Title suffix from home page only

Tags: layout, cms, xml, seo

I have give Title suffix in magento system configuration like `| Magento site`. So this 'll add Title to every page in the store as suffix.

But when i goto home page title shows like `Home | Magento site`

**I would like to remove title suffix only from home page.**

So i expect like `Home` as title in home page.

How to do this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have fix this problem by this [**thread**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/231035/)

**Step 1:** Goto Home page in the CMS page editor

**Step 2:** click on design, then enter this XML into the “Layout Update XML” field:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setData"><key>title</key><value>Home</value></action>
</reference>
```

Now the home page title is set as `Home`

Cheers