# Magento 2.1: Disable title suffix just for home page

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml

I've set up title suffix for all pages in **Content > HTML Head > Title Suffix**, so now every page has suffix `| Pagename.tld`

That's all good. But I would like to exclude my **homepage** from this rule.

I have found [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14208/remove-title-suffix-from-home-page-only?newreg=650fe0271e214783b567c549d4f708fb), but it's not working for me.

When I edit the homepage in the CMS and set the **Layout Update XML** as follows:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setData"><key>title</key><value>Home</value></action>
</reference>
```

...or...

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Home</title></action>
</reference>
```

...or...

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setForcedTitle"><title>Home</title></action>
</reference>
```

Nothing changes and my homepage still has the suffix.

I've used the **Flush Magento Cache** button - no change.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: any solution for this?